# Cannot pass the object into the javascript function as a parameter

Tags: javascript, html, scope

I'm building a user signup for a web site. It uses AJAX to send data. I have created an object to store user data and send the object to the server via    function.

`sendUserData(passenger, "user_registration.php");`

Note :

- `signupUser();` is called with a button click in HTML document.
- `sendUserData()` is the function for sending the user details.
- `passenger` is the object which stores the user data.
- `sendUserData();` is in a separate Script linked to the HTML page.(Global Scope)

This is the code I used to do this

```
//Sign Up A User

var signupUser = function () {

// User Object

var passenger = {       
 userName : document.getElementById("userFirstName").value,
 userEmail : document.getElementById("userEmail").value,
 country : document.getElementById("country").value,
 password : document.getElementById("userPassword").value,
 passwordVerify : document.getElementById("userPasswordVerify").value,
 passwordStatus : Boolean
};

// Verifies the password ("password" and "re-enter password")

verifyPassword(passenger.password,passenger.passwordVerify,passenger.passwordStatus);

if (passenger.passwordStatus == true) {

    sendUserData(passenger, "user_registration.php");
    console.log(passenger);
}

};
```

The problem is with invoking the function `signupUser()` on the button, 
the function stops after `verifyPassword();` .

`sendUserData(passenger, "user_registration.php");` invoked in the chrome debugging tool, it gives an error "passenger is not defined at  : 1:13"

Please help me to find an answer.
Thank you.

Edit:

`sendUserData();` function

This is in a separate javascript file linked to the HTML page.

```
function sendUserData (userDetails, destinationPage, functionToExecute) {


         var userDetailsJson = JSON.stringify(userDetails);
         var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200 ) {
           console.log(userDetailsJson);
           window.alert("Successfully Posted");
           console.log(xhr.responseText);

           if(functionToExecute) {

           functionToExecute();
           }

             }
         };

         xhr.open("POST", destinationPage, false);
         xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
         xhr.send("m=" +userDetailsJson);
     }
```

Comment: Can you show the code of `sendUserData` function?

Comment: Yes. I will add it to the end of my question.

Answer (score 0):

So this hinges on `passenger.passwordStatus == true` not working out.

You initialised it as `passwordStatus: Boolean` which already doesn't do what you think it does.

Then you pass the parameter to the `verifyPassword` function, which presumably looks something like:

```
function verifyPassword( password, retype, status) {
    // verify...
    status = true;
}
```

This *reassigns* `status` and does not affect `passenger.passwordStatus` in the outer scope at all.

Therefore, when it comes time to check the status, you're still comparing `Boolean == true`, which is never going to work.

You probably want something more like:

```
if( verifyPassword( passenger.password, passenger.passwordVerify)) {
    sendUserData(...);
}
```

Have `verifyPassword` do either `return true;` or `return false;` as required.

And get rid of this `passenger.passwordStatus` thing entirely.

Comment: Can you please explain me about not working of ````passenger.passwordStatus````  ? I'm still not fully clear on that.

Comment: ````var verifyPassword = function (password,passwordVerify,user) {
 if (password === passwordVerify) {
  user = true;
  console.log(user);
  
 } } ````  This is the verifyPassword function.

Comment: You can just get rid of the function entirely and just do `if(passenger.password == passenger.passwordVerify) { sendUserData(...); }`

Comment: @ NiettheDarkAbsol   Thanks for your support. Anyway i found a way to use that, making ````user```` inside the function into ````user.passwordStatus```` just works. Sorry i'm not disregarding your advice. just wanted to find a way to solve this.